# AppDynamics - monitoring of services

Tags: health-monitoring, appdynamics

I have a problem with my health rule configuration. All I want is to have health rule which will be checking if service is running or not. I have two types of services:

1. IIS
2. Standalone services

The problem is that some services are recognized as critical due to health rule violation. For example, I have two exactly the same services on two hosts and the only difference is that one of them is in use not so often. Due to lack of activity on this service appdynamics pointing me it as critical.
Most probably I have done something wrong. Any ideas?
I'm struggling with it as additional task. Tried appdynamics community website but nothing which could point me solution.
Here's my health rule configuration :
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor only your worker processes of IIS and Standalone Service, You can use CLR Crash event on your policy configuration.

AppDynamics automaticaly creates CLR Crash Events If your IIS or Standalone Service are crashed.

You can find the details of CLR Crash Events:
https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO45/Monitor+CLR+Crashes

Also, Sample policy configuration: 
[Policy Configuration Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mloax.png)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)